# Flask, Nginx, Gunicorn - Package Import Causes 502 Bad Gateway (it was Environment Variables)

Tags: python, linux, nginx, flask, environment-variables

*I was 99% through writing the question when I realised what the answer was, so I figured I may as well post it anyway - with the answer - in case it can help someone*

I've had a flask app up and running for quite a while now with no issues.

In my app's `__init__.py` I added a simple import statement at the top of the page: `import thepackage` after all of the usual flask and sqlalchemy imports.

- If I launch python interpreter from within the virtual environment `import thepackage` works.
- In the interpreter `from app import thepackage` also works.
- Flask's dev server works: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` serves the webpage when I visit `my.ip.adr.ess:5000`
- As too does gunicorn, `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app` serves the webpage at `my.ip.adr.ess:5000`.
- However, enabling nginx and trying to reach the page at the 
  `websitesdomain.com` throws the 502. This is an example of the `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

> 2018/03/09 03:07:56 [crit] 12444#12444: *2 connect() to
>   unix:/home/me/myapp/myapp.sock failed (2: No such> file or directory)
>   while  connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server:
>   websitesdomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://unix:/home/me/myapp/myapp.sock:/", host: "websitesdomain.com"

- If I remove the import, everything works just as it has always done.
- I have double checked the path to the virtual env that I've set in `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service`, but Flask and gunicorn are in there there's no issues around them.

*Then I realised*

Comment: You can make this more useful for future readers by adding a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was environment variables.

The package being imported relied upon environment variables that were defined in my `~/.profile`. Of course, when executing from within my home directory, these are available to Python interpreter, the Flask dev server and gunicorn from the command line.

But, the app isn't being served in my home environment, rather a systemd unit file that creates the socket and feeds gunicorn off of it.

This was all I had to do:

```
/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service
[Unit]
...
[Service]
...
Environment='PATH=/home/me/path/to/my/venv/bin'
# Added all of the required environment variables in here
Environment='variable_name=variable value'
Environment='another_var=anothervalue'
...
```

The service could't start because of the package trying to connect to a database with a host and password of None (result of `os.getenv('varname')` where `varname` doesn't exist. Because the service couldn't start, the socket was never created and that is why the nginx was logging the errors about not finding the socket.

I lost a lot of hours on this, hopefully this saves someone the same trouble one day!